# org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure cannot be resolved in eclipse

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I imported the spring-boot-1.1.10.RELEASE.jar into my j2ee project.
But i can not found the class of autoconfigure.
Here is code:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
     }
 }
```

The Compile error:

The import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure cannot be resolved

Comment: That import statement is wrong.... It should contain a class or * but now it is a partial package. Another tip instead of hunting for jars yourself I strongly suggest you use something like maven or gradle to manage your dependencies.

Comment: What is "*j2ee project*" in this context?

Comment: In fact,this code from the official documentation .Here is link:https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ . I can't found the problem.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem and I tried above solutions. But I have found a different issue.

In latest **springframework**, this  `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder`  has been moved to
    `org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder`. so you have to edit in *import*

And then you will notice that you have to use `DataSourceBuilder.create(classLoader)` 
 instead of `new DataSourceBuilder(classLoader)`

Answer (score 9):

Go to your maven repository directory
For windows on below path
`C:\Users\YourUser\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot`
Then delete `spring-boot-autoconfigure` folder.

Now go to eclipse and do maven update.

Comment: I already delete all the springframework package, and no changes

Answer (score 3):

There is a copy/paste error - the code from the official documentation (https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) is:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

The code in the question is missing ".EnableAutoConfiguration" in the first line.

Comment: I'm getting the same error too, but my import line is not missing any text?! Is this only for java ee? I was following this tutorial btw: https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/ and gradle import works fine.

Comment: Exactly the same error "The import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure cannot be resolved"?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else has this issue, I was able to solve this by deleting the spring-boot-autoconfigure artifacts from my local Maven repository and updating my project in Eclipse (which re-downloads the artifacts).

Answer (score 1):

if you are using eclise then Right button on project -> Maven -> Update Project

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IntelliJ IDEA Right click on project -> Maven -> Reimport
Also, try "Generate source and update folder" below the reimport if above method doesn't work. No need to delete any spring or maven folder or files.